# Check if doctrine relations are correct

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is it possible to check if the relations between models are correct?

Im looking for cli command or something like Symfony2 profiler which shows wrong relations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a build-in command that Validate that the mapping files are correct and in sync with the database:

```
./bin/doctrine help orm:validate-schema
```

> 'Validate that the mapping files are correct and in sync with the
>   database.'

In the symfony2 doctrine bundle  exists two command instead:

```
doctrine:schema:validate
```

> The doctrine:schema:validate checks the current mappings  for valid
>   forward and reverse mappings.

and

```
doctrine:mapping:info
```

> The doctrine:mapping:info shows basic information about which 
>   entities exist and possibly if their mapping information contains
>   errors or  not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when Im using command you typed first I got error

```Warning:  require_once(Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/my_page/vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine.php on line 20```

version 2.2.*

Comment: try with `php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:validate-schema`

Comment: `Could not open input file: vendor/bin/doctrine` is version 2.2.x not to old ?

Comment: very strange: hovenever the doc don't tell moch more http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html

Comment: this is definitely the correct answer and 2.2 is not too old, just need to get the validate command running which is probably depending on your OS as well

Answer (score 1):

"Using custom column definition trigger schema update every time":
"This is a known limitation that we cannot fix."
https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2666#issuecomment-283772609